# django csv import automatically

Tags: python, mysql, django, csv, django-models

i'm Marcello from italy, i'm new in python and django. I ask a question to get info for my project in django.

I've created a project that have two tables, my problem is that how get data automatically from csv, i will create an ftp server that stored csv.txt and update the tables (for example every day).

Now i update with Django import / export manually. I would like that django read csv files and update db then delete.

Thank you very much for all your support!!!

my models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse



class AnagraficaCliente(models.Model):
    codice_cliente = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True, 
                                      null=False, unique=True)
    ragione_sociale = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    ragione_sociale_dest = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    cognome = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    ragione_sociale = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    indirizzo = models.TextField(blank=True)
    cap = models.CharField(max_length=5, blank=True)
    piva = models.CharField(max_length=11, blank=True)
    vatnumber = models.CharField(max_length=13, blank=True)
    ragione_sociale_dest = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    indirizzo_dest = models.TextField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        #return self.ragione_sociale + " " + self.codice_cliente
        return self.ragione_sociale_dest + " " + self.indirizzo_dest 

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "AnagraficaCliente"
        verbose_name_plural = "AnagraficaClienti"




class Tracking(models.Model):
    track = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False, unique=True, 
                             primary_key=True)
    passaggio1 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    passaggio2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    passaggio3 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    passaggio4 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    passaggio5 = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    consegna = (
        ('C', 'Consegnato'),
        ('N', 'Non consegnato'),
    )
    consegnato = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=consegna)

    #consegnato = models.BooleanField(blank=True)
    #esito = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    flag = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True)
    AnagraficaCliente = models.ForeignKey(AnagraficaCliente, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='trackings')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.track

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Tracking"
        verbose_name_plural = "Trackings"
```

I make a script that read from trackingtest.csv and store in result_str_csv_anag_index_8_list then read from anagraficatest.csv and insert in mysql, after this,i get a query from table tracking_anagraficacliente ( 
previously entered in mysql previously) and i get last field data to store in result_str_query_anag_index_8_list then compare result_str_csv_anag_index_8_list in result_str_query_anag_index_8_list, if foreign key is correct.

All of this work with a cron in linux but i'd like to implement inside  django (in backend) with alert, (for example button red or green if the insert work fine).

I hope to explain well what I have done, i'm beginner ;)

Thank you.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import csv
import MySQLdb, time

sql_anag= """
        INSERT INTO tracking_anagraficacliente 
        (codice_cliente,nome,cognome,ragione_sociale,indirizzo,cap,piva,vatnumber,ragione_sociale_dest,indirizzo_dest)
        VALUES 
        (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
                                                    -- no primary key  aggiornata

        nome   = VALUES(nome),
        cognome   = VALUES(cognome),
        ragione_sociale   = VALUES(ragione_sociale),
        indirizzo   = VALUES(indirizzo),
        cap   = VALUES(cap),
        piva   = VALUES(piva),
        vatnumber   = VALUES(vatnumber),
        ragione_sociale_dest   = VALUES(ragione_sociale_dest),
        indirizzo_dest   = VALUES(indirizzo_dest);
        """
    sql_track= """
        INSERT INTO tracking_tracking 

        VALUES 
        (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s) 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
                                                    -- no primary key  aggiornata

        passaggio1   = VALUES(passaggio1),
        passaggio2   = VALUES(passaggio2),
        passaggio3   = VALUES(passaggio3),
        passaggio4   = VALUES(passaggio4),
        passaggio5   = VALUES(passaggio5),
        consegnato   = VALUES(consegnato),
        flag   = VALUES(flag),
        AnagraficaCliente_id  = VALUES(AnagraficaCliente_id);
        """
query_id_anag = """ select codice_cliente from tracking_anagraficacliente; """
#query_id_track = """ select AnagraficaCliente_id from tracking_tracking; """


db = MySQLdb.connect(
        host="localhost",    # your host
        user="xxxxxxx",         # your username
        passwd="xxxxxx",  # your password
        db="lm_cms")        # name of the data base

cur = db.cursor()

with open('trackingtest.csv') as csvfile: #
readCSVQuery = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',') 
next (readCSVQuery) 
list_csv_tracking = [] 
for i in readCSVQuery: 
    trackAnagraficaId = i[8]
    list_csv_tracking.append(trackAnagraficaId) 
result_str_csv_track_index_8 = str(list_csv_tracking).replace(",", 
"").replace("[", "").replace("]", "") 
result_str_csv_anag_index_8_list = result_str_csv_track_index_8.split(' ') 
print ("Risultato CSV Tracking Foreign 
Key",result_str_csv_anag_index_8_list)

def insert_anagrafica():
    with open('anagraficatest.csv') as csvfile: #read CSV anagraficatest
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        next (readCSV) # Jump first line
        for row_anag in readCSV:
            try:
                cur.execute (sql_anag, (row_anag)) #Insert data on mysql
                db.commit() # Commit your changes in the database
                print(row_anag)
            except (MySQLdb.Error, MySQLdb.Warning) as e: #Exception
                print(e)
                db.rollback() # Rollback in case there is any error
                db.close()

def query_anag():
    cur.execute(query_id_anag) #Execute query to get codice_cliente from tracking_anagraficacliente
    results_query_id_anag = cur.fetchall() # Get all data from query and assign to results_query_id_anag
    result_query_anag = str(results_query_id_anag).replace("(", "").replace(")", "").replace(",", "")# Delete ( ) , from results_query_id_anag and convert to string
    result_str_query_anag_index_8_list = result_query_anag.split(' ') # Convert in string from result_query_anag to result_str_query_anag_index_8_list
    print ("Risultato Query anagrafica Codice cliente  ",result_str_query_anag_index_8_list)
    return result_str_query_anag_index_8_list #return value

def insert_tracking():
    with open('trackingtest.csv') as csvfile: #Read Csv
        readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',') #Read csv file
        next (readCSV) #Jump first line
        #print (results_query_id_anag)
        #compare if AnagraficaClienteID in trackingtest.csv is  present in mysql tracking_aanagraficacliente Codice Cliente
        #,if present make the insert  sql_track else no
        for i in result_str_csv_anag_index_8_list: #compare element lists in result_str_csv_anag_index_8_list is present in result_str_query_anag_index_8_list
            if i in result_str_query_anag_index_8_list:
                for row_track in readCSV: # Read all the line in trackingtest.csv
                    try:
                        #print(row_track[0])
                        #print(row_track)

                        cur.execute (sql_track, (row_track)) #Insert data trackingtest.csv in tracking_tracking
                        db.commit() # Commit your changes in the database
                        print ("Insert effettuata con successo ", row_track)
                    except (MySQLdb.Error, MySQLdb.Warning) as e:
                        print (e, "Riga non inserita: ",row_track)
                        #db.close() # disconnect from server
            else:
                print ("Attenzione, una o più righe non sono state inserite")


insert_anagrafica()
time.sleep(2)
(result_str_query_anag_index_8_list) = query_anag() #value passed from def query_anag() to insert_tracking
time.sleep(2)
insert_tracking()
```

Comment: when you say gettting csv automatically, how? ftp? local file? http/s? also, can you give example of code you tried? a sample of the csv to be imported? is this an insert and replace or an upsert (update/insert)?

Comment: I thought update db through an ftp server, all data that uploaded on ftp with upsert command. My question is, whatis the best practise? Through script in python that  update and insert on mysql, (with an cron job) or there is anothe solutions  with django?
Thank you.

Comment: You are collecting the file from a ftp server (hopefully sftp) then opening said file and running through the db to see if the record exists, then update and if not insert? cron is the simplest and least bulletproof way to implement. would recommend using cronitor if you go down that route

Comment: could you please post your code? we cannot write all the code for you from scratch? you have to show us what you attempted so far.

Comment: no, no i'm sorry i don't want that you write form me my code, i ask the best way to do, in this week i post the code.
Thank you.

Comment: I've uploaded my script. All of this work with a cron in linux but i'd like to implement inside django (in backend) with alert, (for example button red or green if the insert work fine)